# Vitest runner can't load remoteEntry.js file of the remote modules configured with module federation plugin

Tags: reactjs, micro-frontend, vitest, webpack-module-federation

I have created a react app with vite where I am combining two micro-frontends. in the host app I have configured module federation vite plugin which defines remote entry for the exposed ui second micro-frontend. Something similar to this:

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(), 
    federation({
      name: 'host',
      remotes: {
        'ui': 'http://localhost:3201/assets/remoteEntry.js',
      },
      shared: ['react', 'react-dom', 'react-router-dom'],
    }),
  ],...
});
```

All is working fine, the remote entry is published and exposed in a dev remote url as you see in my previous configuration.

I have vitest as test runner, when I run my test for my main app component I am getting the next error:

[image]

Someone knows how to configure vitest to mock that module federation request of the remote javascript file?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this by any chance? 
I am facing the same issue but in my case with Vite's Federation plugin.

I setup manual mocks for the federated module however it still fails with the same error as above trying to load the remoteEntry.js file which doesn't exist

Comment: I can add here that you should be able to visit remoteEntry.js on the remote app that is serving the file. In dev that might look like `localhost:5000/assets/remoteEntry.js` or something like that. In my case, I can only visit the file from my build folder, but no the in-memory version vite dev is supposed to be serving.

Comment: I had to migrate to webpack by internal desitions but I remember I create a mock file with my mocked components and a mock server that runs on tht test environment and mimiking the remote url.

Comment: Check an approach in the answer bellow

Answer (score 0):

I had to switch to webpack for internal decition, but I remember I did something like this to solve this issue:

First, install [mws](https://mswjs.io/) in your application, then configure your server and your handlers:

```
import { setupWorker } from 'msw';
import { handlers } from './handlers';

export const worker = setupWorker(...handlers);
```

Then in the handlers create a mock for your url remote:

import { rest } from 'msw';

```
export const handlers = [
  rest.get('http://localhost:8080/remoteEntry.js', (req, res, ctx) => {
    // Return a mocked response for the remote entry file
    return res(
      ctx.status(200),
      ctx.set('Content-Type', 'text/javascript'),
      ctx.body('console.log("Hello from the remote entry!")')
    );
  }),
];
```

I also created a mock for that remote entry file:

```
async function __federation_import(name) {
  return null;
}
const get = (module) => {
  return null;
};
const init = (shareScope) => {};
export { get, init };
```

I don't remember exactly how was the implementation but I how give you a ligh on how can you solve the issue.